# How to create a Trigger on table to identify whether a particular record been deleted/updated and store the information of entity updating it?

Tags: database, plsql, triggers

i need to save information in another temp table say , TableTemp having the records being modified and with one more column defining which entity updated it.

Comment: You've tagged this `PL/SQL` which is Oracle's procedural language and MySQL which is a completely separate database.  The Oracle SQL Developer tag makes me suspect that you are using Oracle and the MySQL tag is incorrect.  What "entity" are you talking about?  Are you talking about what procedure called the update?  Something else?

Answer (score 1):

You look like you're just discovering, and ask very wide questions. However, here is a possible solution, assuming the below:

- `a_sqnc` is the sequence you will use in `TableTemp` to keep track of the order of actions in column `NO_ORD` (even though there is also a `D_UPD` column with the modification time).

---

```
create sequence a_sqnc
minvalue 1
maxvalue 99999999
start with 1
increment by 1
nocache;
```

- `TableTemp` will have a `TABLE_NAME` column in order to track changes from different tables. It also have a `PK_VALUE` and `ROW_VALUE` where we store the data that changed. Here is the table creation with useful indexes:

---

```
create table TableTemp (
  table_name VARCHAR2(50) not null,
  action     VARCHAR2(240) not null,
  no_ord     NUMBER(12) not null,
  nature     VARCHAR2(3) not null,
  pk_value   VARCHAR2(4000),
  row_value  VARCHAR2(4000),
  ori        VARCHAR2(250),
  c_user     VARCHAR2(20),
  d_upd      DATE
);

create index AP_D_UPD on TableTemp (D_UPD);
create index AP_NO_ORD on TableTemp (NO_ORD);
create index AP_TABLE_NAME on TableTemp (TABLE_NAME);
```

- Say you have a simple table `BANK` with two columns `PK_val` (the primary key) and `val`:

---

```
create table BANK (
  pk_val VARCHAR2(50) not null,
  val    VARCHAR2(240) not null
);

alter table BANK
  add constraint BK_PK primary key (pk_val)
  using index ;
```

- Use `DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.READ_MODULE(w_sess_mod, w_sess_act)` to know what module and what action operates: I concatenate both in column `ORI` in `TableTemp`;
- `user` Oracle session variable will allow you tracking who did the change in column `c_user`;
- Here is how to create trigger `AUD_BNK` to track changes in table `BANK`; it will categorize in 3 actions: `DELETE`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT` (you can remove the `INSERT` case if needed).

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "AUD_BNK" 
AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON BANQUE
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
    w_a        VARCHAR2(10);
    W_ERRM     VARCHAR2(1000);
    W_CODE     VARCHAR2(1000);
    w_n        VARCHAR2(200) := 'BANK';
    w_id       NUMBER :=  a_sqnc.nextval;
    w_act      v$session.action%type;
    w_mod      v$session.module%type;
    w_ori      TableTemp.ORI%TYPE;

  BEGIN
  DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.READ_MODULE(w_mod, w_act);
  w_ori := 'Module : '||w_mod ||' ; Action : '||w_act;
  ----------------------------------
  -- test which action is for change
  ----------------------------------
  IF UPDATING
  THEN
    w_a := 'UPDATE';
  ELSIF DELETING
  THEN
    w_a := 'DELETE';
  ELSIF INSERTING
  THEN
    w_a := 'INSERT';
  END IF;
  ----------------------------------
  -- Insert into TableTemp 
  ----------------------------------
If w_a in ('UPDATE', 'DELETE') then
  Insert into TableTemp 
       Select w_n, w_a, w_id, 'OLD', :OLD.pk_val, :OLD.val
            , w_ori, user, sysdate
         From Dual;
End if;

-- if you update, there is a new value and an old value
If w_a in ('UPDATE', 'INSERT') then
  Insert into TableTemp 
       Select w_n, w_a, w_id, 'NEW', :NEW.pk_val, :NEW.val
            , w_ori, user, sysdate
         From Dual;
End if;

Exception
When others then
  Begin
    W_ERRM := SQLERRM;
    W_CODE := SQLCODE;
    -- try inserting in case of error anyway
    Insert into TableTemp 
         Select w_n, w_a, -1, 'ERR', 'Grrr: '||W_CODE, W_ERRM
              , w_ori, user, sysdate
     From Dual;
  End;
End;
/
```

### Beware!

This way of tracking every change on the table will deeply impair performances if table changes. But it is great for parameter tables that scarcely change.